# Iterate SQL query over some date strings

Tags: sql, google-bigquery

I have a group of BigQuery tables which collect test results on a day by day basis, each table being named like `various_tests.test_name_20190523`. I have a query which I can run over specified date ranges to find the number of failures and ratio of failures to all tests, but I'd prefer to get a table with several date ranges each as a row in the table, e.g. `BETWEEN "20190901" AND "20190916", BETWEEN "20190916" AND "20191001", BETWEEN "20191001" AND "20191016"`. The columns of each row will be the same as the single-row result here. What's a good way to do this?

```
SELECT
  "20190916" as StartDate, "20191001" as EndDate, 
  SUM(CASE WHEN status IN ("BAD") AND foo = 'bar' then 1 else 0 end) as Bad, COUNT(*) as Total,
  (SUM(CASE WHEN status IN ("BAD") AND foo = 'bar' then 1 else 0 end)/ COUNT(*)) as Ratio
FROM
  `various_tests.test_name_*`
WHERE
  _TABLE_SUFFIX BETWEEN "20190916" AND "20191001"
```

(The real query has several more conditions in the `WHERE` and `CASE` clauses but they are elided for clarity.)

Comment: I don't think BQ allows you to read partitions from a table, so you have to hard code them.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One way is to use scripting. Below example uses `bigquery-public-data.google_analytics_sample.ga_sessions_*` to demonstrate the idea. You can easily adapt it to your case.

Also `date_ranges` can be generated based on your need.

```sql
DECLARE date_ranges ARRAY<STRUCT<s STRING, e STRING>>
  DEFAULT [
   ('20170801', '20170802'), 
   ('20170703', '20170704'),
   ('20170603', '20170604')
   ];
DECLARE index INT64 DEFAULT 0;
CREATE TEMP TABLE result(s STRING, e STRING, cnt INT64); 
LOOP
  IF index = array_length(date_ranges) 
    THEN BREAK;
  END IF;
  BEGIN
    DECLARE date_start STRING DEFAULT date_ranges[OFFSET(index)].s;
    DECLARE date_end STRING DEFAULT date_ranges[OFFSET(index)].e;
    INSERT INTO result
    SELECT date_start, date_end, count(*) cnt
    FROM `bigquery-public-data.google_analytics_sample.ga_sessions_*` 
    WHERE _TABLE_SUFFIX BETWEEN date_start and date_end ;
    SET index = index + 1;
  END;
END LOOP;
SELECT * FROM result;
```

Output

```
+----------+----------+------+
|    s     |    e     | cnt  |
+----------+----------+------+
| 20170703 | 20170704 | 3984 |
| 20170603 | 20170604 | 2933 |
| 20170801 | 20170802 | 2556 |
+----------+----------+------+
```

**Cost**

Same cost as manually change start_date/end_date to run multiple times.

**Performance**

Not as efficient as single query (which you have to manually cook) since multiple INSERT INTO has to be run separately.

**Scalability**

Temp table is still subject to daily DML quota per table, so only 1000 inserts can be done in single script.

Comment: :o) to summarize - I really do not recommend using scripts in cases when set-based single query easily does the work!

Comment: I also put cost/perf/scalability in the end. I personally feel it is simpler, say, to generate a report for whole year 2017. The equivalent would be to write code to generate a set-based query, manually cooking a query with 24 different ranges will be too painful to do.

Comment: in my view - going "script way" in such cases is conceptually wrong and will not educate users with best practices. obviously scripting is great feature - and you as a part of the BQ team deserves respect and applause - but it needs to be used where it needed :o) Also Cost section of your answer is not totally correct - hope you see why (I mean it is not the same as for set-based option)

Comment: Could you share how the cost is different? I didn't see why.

Comment: just run two versions and you will see. obviously that difference is negligible for most of us as it is just 10MB (assuming small size of temp table in this case) for each extra touch of temp table

Comment: INSERT INTO is free of charge on destination table. The only extra cost is to output from temp table.

Comment: yes. that is what I meant! and still this was just "btw" and not the main point of mine :o)

Answer (score 0):

Try below

```
SELECT
  -- "20190916" as StartDate, "20191001" as EndDate, 
  _TABLE_SUFFIX AS Day,
  SUM(CASE WHEN status IN ("BAD") AND foo = 'bar' then 1 else 0 end) as Bad, COUNT(*) as Total,
  (SUM(CASE WHEN status IN ("BAD") AND foo = 'bar' then 1 else 0 end)/ COUNT(*)) as Ratio
FROM
  `various_tests.test_name_*`
WHERE
  _TABLE_SUFFIX BETWEEN "20190916" AND "20191001"
GROUP BY DAY
```

> way of making several date ranges and running the query for each

```
SELECT
  -- "20190916" as StartDate, "20191001" as EndDate, 
  CASE 
    WHEN _TABLE_SUFFIX BETWEEN "20190916" AND "20191001" THEN "20190916"
    WHEN _TABLE_SUFFIX BETWEEN "20180916" AND "20181001" THEN "20180916"
  END AS StartDate,
  CASE 
    WHEN _TABLE_SUFFIX BETWEEN "20190916" AND "20191001" THEN "20191001"
    WHEN _TABLE_SUFFIX BETWEEN "20180916" AND "20181001" THEN "20181001"
  END AS EndDate,
  SUM(CASE WHEN status IN ("BAD") AND foo = 'bar' then 1 else 0 end) as Bad, COUNT(*) as Total,
  (SUM(CASE WHEN status IN ("BAD") AND foo = 'bar' then 1 else 0 end)/ COUNT(*)) as Ratio
FROM
  `various_tests.test_name_*`
WHERE _TABLE_SUFFIX BETWEEN "20190916" AND "20191001" 
OR _TABLE_SUFFIX BETWEEN "20180916" AND "20181001" 
GROUP BY StartDate, EndDate
```

> ... an easier way ...

To avoid repetition of all conditions - try something like below

```
SELECT
  -- "20190916" as StartDate, "20191001" as EndDate, 
  (CASE 
    WHEN _TABLE_SUFFIX BETWEEN "20190916" AND "20191001" THEN STRUCT("20190916" AS StartDate, "20191001" AS EndDate)
    WHEN _TABLE_SUFFIX BETWEEN "20180916" AND "20181001" THEN ("20180916", "20181001")
  END).*,
  SUM(CASE WHEN status IN ("BAD") AND foo = 'bar' then 1 else 0 end) as Bad, COUNT(*) as Total,
  (SUM(CASE WHEN status IN ("BAD") AND foo = 'bar' then 1 else 0 end)/ COUNT(*)) as Ratio
FROM
  `various_tests.test_name_*`
WHERE _TABLE_SUFFIX BETWEEN "20190916" AND "20191001" 
OR _TABLE_SUFFIX BETWEEN "20180916" AND "20181001" 
GROUP BY StartDate, EndDate
```

Comment: Not really what I'm looking for; I don't want results per day, but an easier way of making several date ranges and running the query for each.

Comment: That's somewhat better than doing it repeatedly by hand, I guess

Comment: see yet another update, Yes, I think this is the way for you to go ..